# How to Store text in local storage on click of li in autocomplete vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
export default {
    name: 'searchBar',
    data() {
        
        return {
            users: [{
                id: 1,
                text: "Stainless Steel Round Bars",
                done: false
              },
              {
                id: 2,
                text: "Aluminum Round Bars",
                done: false
              },
              {
                id: 3,
                text: "Brass Round Bars",
                done: true
              },
              {
                id: 4,
                text: "Oil Hardened Drill Rods",
                done: true
              }
            ],
            search: '',
            arrowCounter: -1,
            isOpen: false,
            filteredUsers: [],
        
            open: false,
            current: 0,
            value: '',
            isSearchText: false
    }
    },

    props: {
        suggestions: {
            type: Array,
            required: true
        },

        selection: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            twoWay: true
        }
    },


    methods: {
        setResult(text) {
            this.search = text;
            this.isOpen = false;
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
            console.log(user.text,"here");
          },
        enter() {
            this.selection = this.matches[this.current];
            this.open = false;
        },

    

        onArrow(event) {
            if (this.filteredUsers.length > 0) {
              this.arrowCounter = event.code == "ArrowDown" ? ++this.arrowCounter : --this.arrowCounter;
              if (this.arrowCounter >= this.filteredUsers.length)
                this.arrowCounter = (this.arrowCounter) % this.filteredUsers.length;
              else if (this.arrowCounter < 0)
                this.arrowCounter = this.filteredUsers.length + this.arrowCounter;
              this.setResult(this.filteredUsers[this.arrowCounter].text);
            }
          },

          inputChanged(event) {
            if (event.code == "ArrowUp" || event.code == "ArrowDown")
              return;
      
            this.filteredUsers = [];
      
            if (event.code == "Enter")
              return;
      
            var filtered = this.users.filter((user) => {
              return user.text.match(this.search)
            });
      
            this.isOpen = true
            this.filteredUsers.push(...filtered)
      
      
            // console.log(this.filteredUsers)
          },

      
    
        change() {
            if (this.open == false) {
                this.open = true;
                this.current = 0;
            }
            
            
            if(this.search == "") {
                this.isSearchText = false;
            } else {
                this.isSearchText = true;
            }
            
        },
```

```html
 <input class="form-control bg-light-blue" id="SearchText"  type="text" v-model="search"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @input = 'change'
        @keyup="inputChanged"
        @keydown.down="onArrow"
        @keydown.up="onArrow"
    />
     <ul v-for="(user, i) in filteredUsers" :key="i" class="autocomplete-results"
      v-show="isOpen" :class="{ 'is-active': i === arrowCounter }">
      <li @click="setResult(user.text)">{{ user.text }}</li>
    </ul>
    <span v-if="isSearchText" class="close-icon" @click="clearSearch"></span
```

I am working on autocomplete search, And want to perform an action like, Onclick of li in the autocomplete, I want to store the text values in the local storage on every event.

For example if statred typing stainless from the search, related results will be displayed over there and from the suggested result, i want to click on required one and that particular text value i need to store  inside a local storage on every clik event. and display under autocomplete.

Comment: what are you stuck on?

Comment: Sorry, Struck at logic of onclick of li in the autocomplete, need to store text value on every event

Comment: to answer the title of the question, put a line to save to local storage in `setResult` method, your need to be abit more clear about what you mean by on every event as you don't need to store on every event, if you want to save the entire state, then put state vars (search, arrowCounter, isOpen, open, value, isSearchText) in a single property and use a watcher to see if its changed if it does then save in stoorage, and upon load, load it back into the single value

Comment: Do you need to store the value after onclick or keydown event?

Comment: @JoseRojas, Yes i need to store value onclick.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Thanks for your previous code, Can you please repost the answer, it was matching with my requirment.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Only issue with your previous code is, I need to set limit to store the text value to max 5 only. But now i can as many i need and all values are storing.